# Несмь, несмы, несть

Tags: этимология

Можно ли утверждать, что старославянские словоформы "несмь", "несмы" и "несть", пишущиеся в оригинале через букву **ѣ** представляют собой не что иное, как соединение частицы **ни** с соответствующими словоформами настоящего времени глагола быти, исходя из:

1. примеров, из которых видно, что если между отрицательной частицей и самим глаголом имеется дополнение, то пишется именно **ни**, а не **не**

"...**ни** соломонъ въ всей славе своей **облечеся**..." Мф. 6:29
"...**ни** азъ **глаголю** вамъ коею областию сия творю..." Мк.11:33
"...**ни** отецъ вашъ **отъпуститъ** вамъ согрешений вашихъ..." Мф. 6:15

2. точки зрения части ученых, определяющих звучание буквы **ѣ** именно как **ие**, то есть:

н**и** + **е**сть = н**ѣ**сть, откуда следуют и различия в современном русском и украинском (хлеб/хлиб, белый/билый и т.п.)?

Comment: Голосовал против по той причине, что из примеров (оба от Мф.) ровно ничего не проистекает, и главное: качество фонем ѣ в старосл. и древнерусск. языках уже к X в. отличалось. (Историческая грамматика РЯ. М.В. Иванова 2006)

Answer (score 1):

Там другое строение. Я сейчас не помню. По древу всё смотрелось и называлось. "Есть" и "есмь". Если в древе понятие делится на два других понятия, то можно  видеть их положение и называть это положение соответствующими словами: "я есть то" - опираясь на "есть", значит, что речь о понятии, стоящем ниже по отношению к верхнему. А если "я есмь это", то речь о понятии, которое состоит из других понятий.
Не уверен, могу путать, но надо знать древо понятий, строение, сетку.