# Что такое "древо понятий"?

Tags: синтаксис, недопустимая-метка

Вопрос по содержанию этого [ответа.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448808/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

> "я есть то" - опираясь на "есть", значит, что речь о понятии, стоящем
> ниже по отношению к верхнему.  А если "я есмь это", то речь о понятии,
> которое состоит из других понятий.